# How to add a custom line in .vcxproj file using premake?

Tags: premake

I'm trying to add a custom line in `.vcxproj` file, generated with `premake5`.

My team is using an old version of `premake5` so some of the options are not available(such as `debuggertype`, `compileas` , `ignoredefaultlibraries`, etc).

So I've decided to add them manually to generated `.vcxproj` file.

So far, I've tried to read line by line and add the option where it's applicable, but I find this solution not clean at all.

So the question is, how can I add a custom line in `.vcxproj` file, using `premake` ?

Answer (score 0):

usually this is done by overriding some premake internal functions in your script

```
premake.override(premake.vstudio.vc2010, 'treatLinkerWarningAsErrors',  customTreatLinkerWarningAsErrors)
```

where customTreatLinkerWarningAsErrors is a function in our script. 
This function will receive the old overriden function as a param in case you need to call it.